# Easier document checkout for SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, check-out

I have been tasked with finding an easier way to check out documents in SharePoint 2016.  In the old environment, the ribbon appeared when the user clicked on a document and the check out option was right there.  In 2016, they have to right-click and go to Advanced to get to the check out option.  This question is not about a debate over whether this is easy enough...

Is there a way to get the ribbon to show up when clicking on a document in SP 2016?  Or is there some other way that is only one step instead of two?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible to get a screenshot of what you see? The reason is I have SharePoint 2016. The ribbon is still there, with the check in / check out options still in the same place as in 2010 and 2013. Would just like to see what you are describing.

Comment: Hi Shaun, are you using Modern Team site? because modern Team site we dont have ribbon. in Modern site you can select the document and there will be one layer ribbon appears on Top, you have to click three ... dots and then click on Check Out option

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we have to right-click and go to Advanced to get to the check out option  in SharePoint 2016.

There is another way is to choose FILES tab and check out.

[image]